# How to determine whether object is a NSNumber

Tags: objective-c

I am looping through an NSMutableArray and want to know how I can determine whether an array item is in fact an NSNumber or whether its something else e.g. NSString?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try

```
if([[array objectAtIndex:myIndex] isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])
{
//do stuff for NSNumber
}
else
{
//not NSNumber
}
```

quick edit to put in if statement :)